# Desktop application loopback connections - reliable and safe?

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, desktop-application, loopback

I am writing a Desktop application for professional users using C++.  My current design relies on a third-party C++ component whose API is based on TCP/IP.  To integrate this component might involve modifying it to replace the networking code with a conventional C++ API.

It would be a lot easier if I could leave the component unmodified and communicate with it in the way it expects - over the network.  To do so I would need to run the component as a server listening on some high port for loopback connections.

I have two concerns with this loopback approach.  Can anyone allay or confirm my fears?

**Reliability and performance**
The loopback connection might fail, be blocked or intercepted by antivirus software.  Something like this: [Loopback connections working in user's context but not working from Local System account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366212/loopback-connections-working-in-users-context-but-not-working-from-local-system)

**Security**
I am not too concerned about someone sniffing my loopback packets but I don't want my server to become a security risk itself.  Is it risky to have a process listening on some high port?

Do many desktop applications operate like this?

I am initially developing on Windows but may move to Mac and Linux in future so this question applies to all the common desktop OSs.

Comment: What's the nature of this third-party component? Depending on what it is, I would be surprised if it didn't have some kind of "local" version that does not involve TCP/IP. Ask your vendor if there's a non-networked version.

Comment: The best way I can describe it is "a bit like a web server".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reliability: if component itself is reliable then there's no problem with listening to loopback interface. If component is not reliable then it's better to talk with it via loopback interface instead of calling it's functions directly. You can easily handle disconnects and restart component to continue working, but if you would link to the component and component will fail - your app will fail too.

Performance: There's some performance penalty. Not really big with current CPU power. It should be acceptable for most applications.

Security: component should bind to localhost address to avoid security issues. But local 3-d party software (virus) software with sufficient access level can intercept or even modify communication streams. Same for any other method of communication.

Loopback connections are widly used (java uses it for intercommunication, named used it for master service control, etc.)